# jQuery hover function to display an overlay but closes when hover displayed content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am a little new to JS / jQuery and have done a hover function so when hover a link it shows a hidden DIV area but when I go to then hover over the div area shown of course it closes. I would like that if I then go into the content area won't close but stay open but then if leave that area would close?

JS:

```
$('.mini-cart').hover(
  function () {
    cartOpen();
  }, 
  function () {
    cartClose();
  }
);



var overlay = $("#cart_slide");
  var cartContainer = $("#cart_over");

  function cartOpen() {
    cartContainer.fadeIn("slow");
    overlay.addClass("overlay");
  }

  function cartClose() {
   cartContainer.fadeOut("medium");
   overlay.removeClass("overlay");
  }
```

HTML:

```
<a class="mini-cart">hover link</a>
<div id="cart_over" style="display:none;">testing</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce the usage of a flag (`isCartOpen`) variable which is going to control the whether the `DIV` should be displayed or not.

See this **[working JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/x2pbx3mL/)** and find below the related code:

```
var isCartOpen = false;

$('.mini-cart, #cart_over').hover(
  function() {
    isCartOpen = true;
    cartOpen();
  },
  function() {
    isCartOpen = false;
    setTimeout(cartClose, 1000); // after 1 sec
  }
);

var overlay = $("#cart_slide");
var cartContainer = $("#cart_over");

function cartOpen() {
  cartContainer.fadeIn("slow");
  overlay.addClass("overlay");
}

function cartClose() {
  if (isCartOpen)
    return;
  cartContainer.fadeOut("medium");
  overlay.removeClass("overlay");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to separate your open/close functions . Look at the following:

```
$('.mini-cart').hover(
    cartOpen();
);
 // You'll need to create a close button.. ex. <div class="close-button"></div>

$(".close-button").click(function(){
      cartClose(); 
});
```